# Battery isolation circuit with inverted logic

Tags: pullup, pmos, pulldown

I asked a question some time ago in regards to preventing back charging my back-up battery [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661723/silicon-diode-leakage-back-charging-a-battery).  I was just using a diode, but a circuit was suggested for more protection.  It doesn't lend itself to inverted logic though.  I have attempted to fix this but am wondering if this is a good fix.

[image: original]

What is intended is that if 14V is connected, pmosfets will not conduct.  But if 14V is not connected p-mosfets will indeed conduct.

**edit**

I have made the circuit and it behaves as expected with both the 14V and 7V connected.  Also functions when just the 14V is connected. But with just the 7V connected the logic gate is approx 2.6V and the source voltage on M2 is 2.8V (figure2).  It should be 7V though.

[image: revised]

Comment: It should work as per your intention. I saw in your other question that you have mentioned about current leaking back to the 7V. Is that not an issue anymore? Also, when the 14V ramps up from 0 to 14V, are you ok if the output dips to say 2V during the ramp?

Comment: I am not sure if it is safe to eliminate the diode.  I will keep it now just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my simulation results. It seems to work with only 7V present

Case 1: Both 7V and 14V are present

[image]

Case 2: Only 14V present

[image]

Case 3: Only 7V present
[image]

In your case, when only 7V is present, since your gate reads 2.6V, the 14V is not really 0V. It is almost 2.9V. If the 14V does not go all the way to 0V when it is not present, the PMOS will be OFF or very weakly ON because it's VTH is around 4V. VGS is just about equal to VTH and so the PMOS is OFF (or weakly ON) and you will not get 7V at the output. Culprit is 14V not going to 0V which you need to understand as to why it happens.

**Edit:** The PMOS choice of IRF9530 was just for simulation purpose as it is the default one in circuitlab simulator. For your application, you need to use a PMOS that has low enough VTH (say around 2V) and meets the VDS, VGS, IDS & RON requirements.

Comment: You are correct.  I am measuring 3.65V on the 14V line when it is powered down.  So I disconnected the leads of the variable DC power supply and it still reads 3.65V.  Then I realized I didn't have the diode in place instead it was just a wire.  Put the diode there and everything worked as you have shown

Comment: I am not sure how a diode fixed it though. May be it just reduced the voltage on 14V supply from 3.65V to 3.65V-diode drop. The PMOS gate still did not go to 0V right?